# linux cp command different behavior between cmd line and shell script.

Tags: linux, shell

When building gcc-4.8.1, I met a cp command as following:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
fname="cp.sh"
cp -v $fname.{,.bk}
```

It will occurs error when execute this script:

```
  <29>pli[1050]@~/workspace/shell*0 > sh cp.sh
  + fname=cp.sh
  + cp -v cp.sh{,.bk}
  cp: missing destination file operand after âcp.sh{,.bk}â
  Try 'cp --help' for more information.
  <30>pli[1051]@~/workspace/shell*0 >
```

But when type it on cmd line directly, it works well as expected. It is very in comprehensive to me.\n

```
  <28>pli[1049]@~/workspace/shell*0 > cp -v cp.sh{,.bk}
  cp.sh -> cp.sh.bk
  <29>pli[1050]@~/workspace/shell*0 > ^C
```

Comment: Try using `bash` instead of `sh`. I think I've had this issue before, and doing that solved it.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. sh -> dash by default.

Comment: Make sure you're building outside of the `src` folder. I suggest you read through the [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) especially the sections on `gcc`.

Comment: Yes. I built gcc follow the steps of LFS 7.4 chapt5, and build mkdir outside of src folder.

Comment: If you prefer `bash` over `dash`, on Debian you can do `dpkg-reconfigure dash` and set `bash` as default shell.  Any "performance" benefits using `dash` are negligible in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build `gcc` with "bash". On Ubuntu derived distributions "/bin/sh" in not linked to "/bin/bash" (but to "/bin/dash"); this is documented in the Ubuntu [wiki here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). I would suggest using a "ppa" if possible.